# Navigation issue in swagger document while clicking a specific url

Tags: swagger-editor

i have created the swagger documents for my rest-apis , there is a navigation issue by clicking a url ,

for example url is https://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/updatePet (this is petstore url )  when i click it it will redirecting to again main page , istead of specific url , please help me to overcome fro this

Answer (score 1):

You have run into known issues with anchor links in Swagger UI:
[Markdown link open a new tab/window](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3473)
[HTML links to anchors do not work (`<a href="#.."></a>`)](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3958)

There is no workaround (at the moment). You can subscribe to these issues to get notified when they are fixed.