# Swagger UI, how to avoid anchor links opening a new tab/window

Tags: hyperlink, swagger-ui

Not sure if this is possible, we have the following in our **open_api.yaml** for our API created with Swagger:

```
paths:
    /stats/team/game-sbz:
        get:
            tags:
                - Team Game Stats
            summary: Game shooting-by-zone statistics for teams
            description: Get game shooting-by-zone statistics for teams
            operationId: getSbzStatsTeamGame
            parameters:
                - name: competitionIds
                  in: query
                  description: see [/competitions](#/Entities/getCompetitions) for more info on available competitions.
```

When `[/competitions](#/Entities/getCompetitions)` is clicked, a new tab is created that links to this. This UX is arguably worse than replacing `[/competitions](#/Entities/getCompetitions)` with an unclickable `/competitions`. We also tried `<a href="http://localhost:8080/api-docs/#/Entities/getCompetitions">/competitions</a>`, however this link, when clicked, does not jump the page down to the /competitions endpoint, instead the page stays exactly where it was.

Is there anyway to link in a parameter description to another endpoint **without** said link opening a new tab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigation issue in Swagger UI document while clicking a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54218677/113116)

Comment: @Helen - unfortunately, I guess so, although that posting is a few years old now. There's still no way to do this / no workaround?

Comment: It's still an issue, yes.